# Do I need to worry about the water dripping from the cut branch of the tree?

Tags: water, trees

It's been two month since the branches were cut, and the water has been dripping from it since then; a small pond has formed. Is this something to be worried about?

[image]

Comment: Is that tree sitting in a layer of asphalt/tarmac? It seems I like that layer was applied at some later point in the tree’s life? That would worry me at least as much as the excessive sap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's as serious an issue as others do. For one thing, my father just completed this year's sap collection season for making Maple syrup. If you saw how much sap comes out of a single small tree you'd be less concerned.

For another, it seems like the wound is sealing over as nature intended. I have oak trees which *naturally* leak all summer in a similar manner. It's how trees do.

For yet another, two months ago was basically winter in much of the world. That's not a bad time to do pruning.

Unless you encounter an extraordinarily severe drought this year, I'd expect a tree of that size to recover without issue.

Answer (score 4):

Whoever cut that *when* they cut it was not a very good excuse for a tree surgeon.

That's not water, it's sap. Eventually it will stop, but doing major surgery on hardwoods in the early spring is exceedingly stupid, because this happens, and the tree is severely weakened by what is, essentially "blood loss" - and it would not happen (either "at all" or to nearly that extent) if the same cut was made in the summer.

*The cut facing us may also be cut too close to the trunk. The one we see the side of looks OK, but this one looks like it might have been cut beyond the "branch collar" which is the formation at the base of the branch that will, if not cut off, more quickly heal over a cut branch*

Comment: This is saddening; i hired a contractor to cut the tree. As a new homeowner, I needed that tree cut as it was extending to neighbors property.

Comment: The wood is also rotting from the inside out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZgM0XSvVQA. I mean, it's been doing that for awhile.

Comment: Sadly there are plenty of people trimming trees who have tools but no clue. Whether they're general building contractors or general gardeners they're not qualified tree surgeons and that's what you need for big cuts.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, That's sap, not water. It's very unhealthy for the tree to be loosing that much. Check with your agricultural department or department of forestry to see if they can recommend a sealer or cap for that. Growing up in the midwest, our tree trimmers always coated the cut with a tar like substance but as @Ecnerwal pointed out, that's no longer being done.

Comment: ...and the tar-like substance is long since discredited. More harm than good. *e.g.* https://www.purdue.edu/fnr/extension/tree-wounds-and-healing/